# My touchpad is recognised as a mouse. How can I fix it?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, touchpad, hp

My touchpad is recognised as a mouse, and for this reason I cannot disable it while I'm typing nor can I take advantage of scrolling and multi-touch features that my touchpad should support.

My machine is a netbook HP Mini 210 1000SA and I'm currently using Natty 32bit, but I have experienced this same issue before with Lucid and Maverick.

I've searched the entire web looking after a solution for this, but I haven't found anything but lots of people experiencing the same problem, including users of different machines.

I really hope that there is a solution for this issue or at least that it will be fixed in Natty, as it is really annoying.

Is anyone able to provide us (me and the hundreds of poor souls with the same problem) a relief?

Thank you very much indeed!

P.S.: Information that might help:

```
angelo@XXX:~$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=20000 0 20 0 0 0 0 500f 2100002 3803078 f900d401 feffffdf ffefffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HP WMI hotkeys"
P: Phys=wmi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=23
B: KEY=40 0 0 0 7 0 0 2100400 0 0 0 0
B: SW=22

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=064e Product=f100 Version=0332
N: Name="HP Webcam-50"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1d.7-4/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B    : EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=7
B    : KEY=70000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel Mic at Ext Front Jack"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel HP Out at Ext Front Jack"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

angelo@XXX:~$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Webcam-50                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]

angelo@XXX:~$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i synaptics
[    21.058] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event7)
[    21.058] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    21.058] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[    21.058] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Device: "/dev/input/event7"
[    21.068] (--) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found 3 mouse buttons
[    21.068] (--) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found relative axes
[    21.068] (--) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found x and y relative axes
[    21.068] (II) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Configuring as mouse
[    21.068] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    21.068] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    21.068] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: MOUSE)
[    21.069] (II) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: initialized for relative axes.
[    21.069] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    21.069] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    21.069] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    21.069] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    21.070] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse0)

angelo@XXX:~$ xinput --list-props 11
Device 'PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (135):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (137): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (255): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (256):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (257):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (258):    10.000000
    Evdev Axis Inversion (259): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (261):  0
    Axis Labels (262):  "Rel X" (145), "Rel Y" (146)
    Button Labels (263):    "Button Left" (138), "Button Middle" (139), "Button Right" (140), "Button Wheel Up" (141), "Button Wheel Down" (142)
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (264):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (265):  50
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (266):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (267):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (268):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (269):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (270): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (271):  0

angelo@XXX:~$
```

Comment: This is best reported as a bug against the appropriate package(s), so hopefully a fix could go upstream.

Comment: Bug reported at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/749606

Comment: @user13466: good ^^

Comment: @roland-taylor: Unfortunately I had to dismiss the bug report as I've learned from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection that "In case Touchpad features like scrolling, tapping, etc do not work at all. Common symptom is absence of 'Touchpad' Tab is not there in System>Preferences>Mouse.This may be a wrong detection by the xserver or the kernel itself. So xserver-xorg-input-synaptics has nothing to do with it.".

Comment: @roland-taylor: It does'n seems to be a problem with the kernel as 'PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad' can be found in 'xinput --list'. If it is not a problem neither with  'xserver-xorg-input-synaptics' or the kernel, according to the information in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection it might be a problem with HAL. However, when I tried to perform the tests listed in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingHal , I haven't got any valid responses from the HAL debugging tests. I want to help but I don't want to waste the develpers' time filling a bug report for the wrong package. Any ideas?

Comment: @user13466 the developers can reassign the bug to the right package. It will not be HAL because HAL is no longer being used.

Comment: Yuo haven't specified if you've install the utouch ppa or the synaptic dkms module.

Comment: I don't think we can do anything useful here. Please open a bug report and let developers decide what to do with it.

Comment: Agreed with @htorque. Voting to close as too localized.

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/749606) and as such is now closed.

Comment: How can it be a bug for more than 6 months and not be solved?